# SSH key works if the file name is the default, but not when it's renamed

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, ed25519

I wanted to generate an SSH key for my GitHub account. Following [this](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) guide, I ran `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my@email.com"`. I gave it the filename `github_main` and put in a passphrase. All that worked fine.
Running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_main` gave a problem, but I resolved that by running the command with a slightly different path. It returned `Identity added: C:/Users/brent/.ssh/github_main (my@email.com)`, so I assumed everything worked.

I then tested the connection with `ssh -T git@github.com`. It said I was successfully connected, but GitHub doesn't provide shell access, which looked to me like it worked.

I added the SSH token to my GitHub account, no problems there either. Then, I tried cloning one of my repositories through SSH, which strangely didn't work; it gave the following result:

```
Cloning into 'my-repo'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried cloning the same repository with the HTTPS and that worked fine. After about an hour of googling and searching, I had read multiple times that the file name has no influence on the result, yet I decided to try renaming the files to the original names. I renamed the public key to `id_ed25519.pub` and the private key to `id_ed25519`. This time, when I tried cloning the repository with the SSH, it asked for the passphrase and cloned the repository. This confuses me a lot, especially since everything I've read so far has told me that the file name does not matter.

Although it works with having the files named `id_ed25519`, I'd still like to rename the files since this file name tells me nothing about the key, and that I can only have one key encrypted like this.

Comment: Define that key in your config file under IdentityFile https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/config

Comment: @Martheen I don't have a `ssh_config` file in the `.ssh` folder, nor do I seem to have the `/etc/` folder they're referring to. I'm also not sure where they want me to add the `-i` flag.

Comment: Just create the file, it's only a text file. See the example in https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not using all the default names, which means you need to tell ssh where you put things. To avoid repeating yourself every time, do that in its config, which it looks for in `~/.ssh/config`. First line: `addkeystoagent yes`. Second line: `host github`. Third line: `hostname github.com`. Fourth line: `identityfile path/to/your/privateidentityfile`. The `host` line starts a block, you can now say `git clone git@github:yourghid/yourrepo` and that's enough. You can even add a `user git` line for the host, then `git clone github:yourghid/yourrepo`. Spelling is up to you, if I was doing a lot of it I'd spell things like `gh`, `host gh` `user git` `hostname github.com` `identityfile ~/.ssh/id_gh`, then `git remote add linux gh:torvalds/linux` works.

Say `man 5 ssh_config`, man section 5 is file formats. Bash completion knows this stuff, say `man 5` and hit tab a couple times to tell it no really show me all the file formats you've got doc for.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you a lot! Though, to have it work with the default GitHub clone commands, I changed `host github` to `host github github.com`.